# Modifying HTML links with new location in Jenkins Email Extension

Tags: jenkins, email

[Cucumber Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRSG2.png)
I have a cucumber report and want to have the report in the body of the email using Jenkins email extension after every build. Before jenkins sends out the report ,links of the features needs to be updated with new build location, where the cucumberreport.html content should be updated with the latest build link.

Can you help how this can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to achieve this

First one is using a groovy script:

```
reportFile = <location and filename of report>
oldURL = <url in report>
newURL = <url for sending>     
sTemplate = readFile "${reportFile}"
sTemplate = sTemplate.replace(oldURL,newURL)

emailext body: "${sTemplate}", subject: "Cucumber Report", to: receiver@email.com
```

The other option is (if you are on a linux) using sed:

```
sh """
OLDSTR="<url in report>";NEWSTR="<url for sending>";file="<location and filename of report>";sed -i -- 's#'"$OLDSTR"'#'"$NEWSTR"'#g' "$file"
"""
emailext body: "<location and filename of report>", subject: "Cucumber Report", to: receiver@email.com
```

CAVEAT: the option using sed will modify the file on disk